# How to pass an array from a form to a controller method?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have an edit form in which I build an array of numbers. When I click submit, I will do " :method => :sort ". How do I make it so my sort method in my controller can use the array. The edit form is done in haml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more solutions to it but I prefer this one:

In the model for which the form is for add:

```
attr_accessor :order_ids
```

Now in the haml code i.e., in the form add:

```
%input{name: "model_name[order_ids][]", type: "hidden", value: order}
```

And in the controller in:

```
params[:model_name][:order_ids]
```

you should get the array. Just change the `model_name` to the name of you model.

And why are you sending:

```
= f.submit "Save Changes", :method => :sort
```

method as sort. This is not correct. If you want to send the form to the action `sort` in your controller then that needs to be specified in the `form url`

Suppose you have a action named `sort` in `lists_controller` and in your routes you define it as:

```
put '/sort', to: 'lists#sort', as: list_sort
```

Then in the form you can give it as:

```
= form_for @list, :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true, url: list_sort_path } do |f|
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm relatively new to this so this is a little confusing for me. I don't see where I'll need the attribute and what that exactly is.

As of now I have an array called "order" and I have this line

= f.submit "Save Changes", :method => :sort, class: "button btn btn-primary w-100"

How can I send the list order to the order array so that the sort method in the controller can use it. And how would I access it from within the controller?

Comment: Just paste your form and what you want to send as array so I can help further. The question doesn't has any details.

Comment: I put part of the code in the question. I want to send order to sort method.

Comment: I'm getting

undefined local variable or method `order' for #< <Class:0xa9f0638>:0x3b3c208>

from the code I add to the form.

Comment: Underneath the 2nd line

Comment: Oh I got it. I have to put it under 

 - order = []

right?

Comment: you `order` variable is defined after that currently that is why you are getting that error. Paste it below that

Comment: One more question. You said doing

:method => :sort

was incorrect. How do I call the sort method when I click the "Save Changes" button.

Comment: show me the `form_for` defined above. In that you can specify a attribute `url` and in which you will type in the path of the `sort` action

Comment: The form_for already says

`= form_for @list, :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true } do |f|`

Comment: so this would take you to the `update` action of `lists_controller`

Comment: I have updated the answer. And it is rails convention that if you define as above and the `@list` is in edit form that is a persisted object then it will always take you to the update action as PUT. If you want to override the default behavior then add a `url` attribute in form

Comment: Thanks once again. This is really helping. When I put `params[:model_name][:order_ids]` in the controller I get

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: order_ids`

Comment: It seems that you are using rails 3 if so then add `attr_accessible :order_ids` in the model

Comment: Then I get the error `unknown attribute: order_ids`

Comment: Is the `attr_accessor :order_ids` placed above the `attr_accessible`?

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't know I had to keep the attr_accessor. It works now but my order array is empty for some reason.